# Store Object in database which have array of objects

Tags: object-oriented-database

How can we store object in database which have array of object inside it.
For ex.

```
Class Foo { 
    public List<object> Bar = new List<object>();
}
```

Can give answer in php or c#.

Comment: opal why u gave -1 did i asked something wrong or wht?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is have table `Foo`, table `Bar`, and table `FooBar`. `Foo` and `FooBar` would have some sort of unique identifier with them, and `FooBar` would have the map. The query you could execute is

```
SELECT Foo.Id AS FooId, Bar.Id AS BarId, Bar.Column1, Bar.Column2
FROM Foo
INNER JOIN FooBar
ON Foo.Id = FooBar.FooId
INNER JOIN Bar
ON FooBar.BarId = Bar.Id
```

Note that I'm no DBA or SQL expert, so there may be a better way of doing this.